# Modificando algunos comportamientos del Django admin en cuanto a sus formularios generados

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-forms

Tengo un modelo el cual estoy manipulando a través del administrador de Django.

El modelo y "su lógica de negocio" me demanda establecer un comportamiento específico en cuanto a su formulario para ingresar datos. Lo que necesito realizar es lo siguiente:

Tengo los siguientes campos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero realizar es que cuando yo seleccione un nombre en el campo `Name`, acorde al valor seleccionado, se me despliegue cierta información (que también será seleccionada) en los campos `Type`, `Freedom Degrees`

Es algo parecido a como cuando uno en los formularios de registro, selecciona un país y acorde a ese país, salen los departamentos/estados/provincias y acorde a las seleccionadas salen las ciudades o municipios.

Esto lo deseo hacer para el modulo de administración que Django me provee, y también lo haría en mi aplicación propiamente.
Sé que hay algunas cosas para [personalizar la interfaz de administración](http://django-fluent-contents.readthedocs.org/en/latest/newplugins/admin.html) o trabajando con [ModelAdmin.form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form) [todo para adicionar comportamientos](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin)

Quería compartir esta inquietud, por si alguien ha realizado cosas por el estilo y si voy por buen camino.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El paquete [**Django Smart Select**](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects) hace toda la magia que estás buscando.

El ejemplo es de países, exactamente:

```
class Continente(models.Model):
        nombre = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Pais(models.Model):
        continente = models.ForeignKey(Continente)
        nombre = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Ubicacion(models.Model):
    continente = models.ForeignKey(Continente)
    pais = models.ForeignKey(Pais)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area)
    ciudad = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    calle = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

El paquete requiere que uses un tipo de campo personalizado, que hace funcionar el paquete:

```
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey 

class Ubicacion(models.Model)
    continente = models.ForeignKey(Continente)
    pais = ChainedForeignKey(
        Pais, 
        chained_field="continente",
        chained_model_field="continente", 
        show_all=False, 
        auto_choose=True
    )
    area = ChainedForeignKey(Area, chained_field="pais", chained_model_field="pais")
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Las propiedad `chained_field` indica cuál es el campo que enlaza en el modelo actual y `chained_model_field` es el campo en el otro modelo.

Solo tienes que seguir las instrucciones de instalación.

1. Agrega `smart_selects` a tu `INSTALLED_APPS`.
2. Crea las rutas en `urls.py` de `smart_selects` para que funcionen los controles Select encadenados, por ejemplo:

   ```
   urlpatterns = patterns('',
       url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
       url(r'^chaining/', include('smart_selects.urls')),
   )
   ```

Es más complicado con campos *Many to Many*, pero el funcionamiento básico es este.

Comment: Amigo @toledano, yo tengo un error con smart-selects, después de la última actualización ya no me sirve.

Comment: @SalahAdDin por favor consulta esta página: http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask